# How to set error message in base in rails' built in validation methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

In rails' built in validation methods like:

```
 validates :email, presence: true
```

and

```
 validates_uniqueness_of :email,   message: " address used "
```

If error occurs, the msg will be: ***"Email is taken"***(default) and ***"Email address used"***. But I want a message like ***"This email address has been taken"***. I can do this in custom validation functions using ***'errors.add(:base, "message")'***.  I do not know how to set the msg to 'base' like that in a built in validation.

Comment: using locals file you can do it...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness:{message: "custom message"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one, let me know i have not tested it. Also really good documentation about validations [LINK](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#message).

```
validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false,
                                     message: "This email %{value} address used" }
```